# how did he conclude that?integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integration

So the question is : Find all continuous functions such that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt= ((f(x)^2)+C$. 
Now in the solution, it starts with this, clearly $f^2$ is differentiable at every point ( its derivative is $f$). So $f(x)\ne0$? I have no idea how he concluded that, this is from Spivak's calculus, if you differentiate it's clearly $f(x)=f(x)f'(x)$ but he said that before even giving this formula help please?
EDIT : I know that $f(x)=f(x)f'(x)$ What  i don't understand is this "clearly $f^2$ is differentiable at every point ( its derivative is $f$). So $f(x)\ne0$" why $f(x)$ mustn't equal $0$?

Comment: The equation you wrote doesn't seem to make much sense: the left hand is *a number*, whereas on the right hand you wrote a squared **function** plus a constant.

Comment: which chapter? which exercise?

Comment: Don't you mean, $f(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$?

Comment: 4th edition, chapter 14, exercise 6 ... Find all continuous functions $f$ satisfying $\int_0^x f = (f(x))^2+C$ for come constant $C \ne 0$ assuming that $f$ has at most one $0$.  No solution is given by Spivak, so steve must mean someone else's solution.

Comment: So, in the 3rd edition, the question was shorter, and in the 4th edition it is expanded into 3 parts (based on how many zeros the solution has); the first part is the one I quoted.

Comment: Since the equation started from an integral equation, so the [tag:integration] tag should be replaced by the [tag:integral-equations] tag.

Answer (score 2):

As DonAntonio pointed out, the left hand side is a **constant** (not a function like the right hand side). I'll assume that you made a typo and that you instead meant to type:
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt$$

---

Note that the left hand side is differentiable at every point, since by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t)dt = f(x)
$$

Hence, since the right hand side equals the left hand side, it follows that $(f(x))^2+C$ is also differentiable at every point.

Comment: The left hand, assuming $\,f\,$ is integrable, is a *number*, so yes: it trivially is differentiable at every point. Did you mean this?

Comment: I assumed that the OP made a typo and meant to write his LHS as:
$$
\int_0^x f(t)dt
$$

Comment: @DonAntonio The left hand is dependent on $x$, so as a function of $x$ it is differentiable.

Comment: Ok @Adriano, then it'd perhaps be a good idea you point out this.

Comment: No @Greebo, the left hand does not depend *directly* from $\,x\,$. Again, as written, that's is a number.

Comment: @DonAntonio It was as first written, but as it is written now, changing $x$ changes the interval and therefore the value, so it's dependent on $x$.

Comment: @Greebo, when you wrote your first comment and I addressed it, the integral's upper limit was $\,b\,$ so it was a number. Now, indeed, is fine

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the problem as follows:

Find all continuous functions $f:\ \Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ defined in some open interval $\Omega$ containing the origin and satisfying the integral equation
$$\int_0^x f(t)\ dt=f^2(x)+ C\qquad(x\in\Omega)$$
for a suitable constant $C$.

Assume $f$ is such a function and that $f(x)\ne 0$ for some $x\in\Omega$. Then for $0<|h|\ll1$ we have
$$\int_x^{x+h} f(t)\ dt=f^2(x+h)-f^2(x)=\bigl(f(x+h)+f(x)\bigr)\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\ ,$$
and using the mean value theorem for integrals we conclude that
$${f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}={f(x+\tau h)\over f(x+h)+f(x)}$$
for some $\tau\in[0,1]$. Letting $h\to0$ we see that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and that $f'(x)={1\over2}$. It follows that the graph of $f$ is a line with slope ${1\over2}$ in all open intervals where $f$ is nonzero. When such a line coming from west-south-west arrives at the point $(a,0)$ on the $x$-axis then $f(a)=0$ by continuity, and similarly, when such a line starts at the point $(b,0)$ due east-north-east, then $f(b)=0$.

The above analysis leaves only the following possibility for such an $f$: There are constants $a$, $b$ with $-\infty\leq a\leq b\leq\infty$ such that

$$f(x)=\cases{-{1\over2}(a-x)\quad &$(x\leq a)$ \cr 0&$(a\leq x\leq b)$ \cr {1\over2}(x-b)&$(x\geq b)\ .$\cr}$$
It turns out that these $f$'s  are in fact solutions to the original problem.

*Proof.* Assume for the moment
$$a\leq0\leq b\ .\tag{1}$$
When $0\leq x\leq b$ then $$\int_0^x f(t)\ dt=0=f^2(x)+0\ ,$$
and when $x\geq b$ then
$$\int_0^x f(t)\ dt=\int_b^x f(t)\ dt={1\over4}(t-b)^2\biggr|_b^x={1\over4}(x-b)^2= f^2(x)+0$$
as well. Similarly one argues for $x\leq0$.

In order to get rid of the assumption $(1)$ we note that when $f$ is a solution of the original problem then  any translate $g(x):=f(x-c)$, $\>c\in{\mathbb R}$, is a solution as well: For all $x\in{\mathbb R}$ we have
$$\eqalign{\int_0^x g(t)\ dt&=\int_0^x f(t-c)\ dt=\int_{-c}^{x-c} f(t')\ dt'=\int_{-c}^0 f(t')\ dt'+\int_0^{x-c} f(t')\ dt'\cr
&=\int_{-c}^0 f(t')\ dt'+f^2(x-c)+C=g^2(x)+C'\ .\cr}$$